# Spotlight not searching Time Capsule drive, indexing enabled

Tags: network, spotlight, time-capsule, search

When using Spotlight search, it is not finding a specific file, which I know is located on my Time Capsule drive, which, of course, is mounted and indexing thereof is enabled.
Please, see below relevant Terminal extract:

```
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mdutil -s /                                                              
/:
    Indexing enabled. 
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mdutil -s /Volumes 
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes:
    Indexing enabled. 
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mdutil -s /Volumes/Time\ Capsule 
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Time Capsule:
    Indexing enabled. 
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -l /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans                     
total 15296
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Martin  staff        0 Jan 15  2012 Icon?
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 Martin  staff      264 Jan 20  2012 Teach Yourself - Afrikaans
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Martin  staff  7761600 Aug  9 09:33 afrikaans woorden.txt
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans -name afrikaans     
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans/ -name afrikaans
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans -name afrikaans 
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans/ -name afrikaans
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

I have tried rebuilding the indexing by adding and removing the drive from the Spotlight Privacy tab.
What should I do? Please help!
Thanks

**UPDATE 1 as per kodliber's suggestion:**
*Have you tried by manually import this file you mention using the command mdimport?*
Yes I have, to no avail.

```
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -l /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans/
total 15296
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Martin  staff        0 Jan 15  2012 Icon?
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 Martin  staff      264 Jan 20  2012 Teach Yourself - Afrikaans
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Martin  staff  7761600 Aug  9 09:33 afrikaans woorden.txt
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mdimport /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans/afrikaans\ woorden.txt
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans -name woorden
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans/ -name woorden
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans -name woorden
Password:
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans/ -name woorden
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

**UPDATE 2 as per Jahhein's question:**
*At the root of the volume, is there a file named .metadata_never_index?*
No, there is no such file.

```
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -la /Volumes/Time\ Capsule | grep .metadata_never_index
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

**UPDATE 3**

Doing the same search using Spotlight via CMD+Spacebar works:
[image]

Comment: At the root of the volume, is there a file named `.metadata_never_index`?

Comment: @Jahhein No, there is no such file.

Comment: Are you trying to find a file within the TM backup using Spotlight? I don't think you can get results from inside a backup in 'normal' search. What happens if you search from within the TM application, using the "Finder" window's search bar?

Comment: @benwiggy No, my problem has nothing to do with Time Machine. I'm trying to find a file on Time Capsule drive, not within Time Machine backup.

Answer (score 1):

(I have not enough reputation to comment your question, so I post a reply - my apologies to the admins.)

Have you tried by manually import this file you mention using the command `mdimport`?

Comment: You may ask OP to drop  in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat

Comment: @kodliber yes, to no avail 
`Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -l /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans/
total 15192
drwx------  1 Martin  staff    16384 Jan 20  2012 Teach Yourself - Afrikaans
-rwx------  1 Martin  staff  7761600 Aug  9 09:33 afrikaans woorden.txt
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mdimport /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans/afrikaans\ woorden.txt
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/Time\ Capsule/Documents/Afrikaans -name woorden
Martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro ~ %`